# Are laymen and environmentalists opposite ends of the spectrum?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

In the following sentence I want to contrast two opposite sides of the society. Those who are not aware and those who are obsessed with environmental issues.

At one end of the spectrum, we have environmentalists, but at the other end I wonder if the word "laymen" is a good choice or not?

> To the **laymen**, there is no connection between agricultural plantation
> and loss of biodiversity, but among **environmentalists**, there is an intense
> debate on this.

Comment: An environmentalist is not a career or specialty. It is a political stance that doesn’t necessarily imply special expertise. Layman or layperson is a nonprofessional in a field.

Comment: ***environmentalist*** and ***layman*** are ***orthogonal*** (whether or not you're a "layman" makes no difference to whether or not you're an "environmentalist"; the terms aren't related, as can be easily established by reference to any dictionary).

Comment: The opposite of *layman* is *expert*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have indicated, "layman" and "environmentalist" are not at different points of a continuum. A "layman" in this soet of use is an ordinary person who lacks special expertise, while an "environmentalist" is a person who takes a particualrt point of view. Some environmentalists also have specialized knowledge, but others do not, and the word does not imply such knowledge.

Also, in the construct "to the X" X should udsually be singular in form, as it is evo9king a typical member od a group. so it shouold be "*to the **layman***" not "**laymen** "

Thus if you want to describe a continuum of expertise, you might write:

> To the layman, there is no connection between agricultural plantation and loss of biodiversity, but among **ecologists**, there is an intense debate on this.

Or "environmental scientists" could be used instead of "ecologists".

If you want to discuss a range of political views, rather than expertise, then some term or phrase should be substituted for "layman" which suggests a person not strongly interested in environmentalism.

Comment: Changing “environmentalist” to a profession changes the meaning of the sentence. With the dearth of context we have, it would make more sense to change “layman” to something more generic like “many people”.

Comment: @ColleenV, yes, changing to a profession changes the meaning. But so does changing "layman" to, a term such as "an ordinary person". Or, rather, I would say that either change **gives** a meaning (a different meaning in each case) to a text that as written has no coherent meaning. Without context the original intended meaning is not clear. That is why i tried to explain what change to make depending on the desired meaning.

Comment: *I want to contrast two opposite sides of the society. Those who are not aware and those who are obsessed with environmental issues.* It seems clear to me the intent is not to compare professionals and non-professionals. This is why I’ve voted to close the question. Your answer is perfectly reasonable and helpful, but there are many other equally valid ways to rewrite that sentence. At its heart this is either a proofreading question or one that can be answered with a dictionary.